# Auto-mounting NFS in AIX at startup

Tags: nfs, automount, aix

I have few NFS file systems which I mount manually after my AIX system boots up. Is there a way I can do it using `/etc/filesystems`?

What would be the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The `mknfsmnt` command will add the appropriate entry to `/etc/filesystems` to mount NFS file systems at boot time - the `I` option does this. For further details read the man page for mknfsmnt or you can read the documentation on the [IBM Webste](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/no.htm). SMIT also provides an excellent interface to this command - command line SMIT - `smitty nfs` will get you to the SMIT panels for NFS.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should look for autofs. See [IBM pages](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-namespace/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example;

```
/var/nfsmount1:
    dev          = "/var/www/html/apacheapp/somedir"
    vfs          = nfs
    nodename     = 192.168.100.202
    mount        = true
    options      = bg,hard,intr,sec=sys
    account      = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command for predefined mount (to make entries in `/etc/filesystems`):

```
#crfs -v nfs -n nodename -d /nfs filesystems -a options=rw,hard,bg,intr -A yes -m /mntpnt
```